# export protractor config after a async function ends

Tags: typescript, protractor

I'm setting the config object to start protractor, and the config object is exported before async function is done, so the field where I am calling the async function from is empty.

Example:

````
const config: Config = {
  directConnect: true,
  SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,
  allScriptsTimeout: 60000,
  stopSpecOnExpectationFailure: true,

  jasmineNodeOpts: getJasmineNodeOpts(),

  baseUrl: env.baseUrl,

  capabilities: capabilities,

  specs: getTestfailed()  <------- This is the async function
)```

exports.config = config


so the config object is exported before specs have been updated.
````

Comment: What is the async action that is occurring within `getTestfailed()`?

Comment: it's doing an http request

Answer (score 0):

You can try following way to update specs

```
return browser.getProcessedConfig().then(function(config) {
        config.specs = //this take array of string
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying many approaches... I decided to do the http request (getTestfailed()) sync, I know is not ideal, but enough for the purpose